# Apache Redirect - case insensitive

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How I can make a robust permanet redirection from a link like https://example.com/products to https://example.com/newPath

The redirection should work case insensitive. For example the call https://example.com/ProDucTs should also work.

I think the solution should contain something like this

RewriteCond ????? [NC]
RewriteRule ?????[L,R=301]

Answer (score 9):

You can set these two rules in your htaccess file

```
RedirectMatch 301 (?i)/android-app  https://play.google.com/app-url
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^products$ /newPath? [L,R=301,NC]
```

In above two rules "?i" and "NC" for case insensitive.